# 100% height for div with absolute positioned image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an image positioned absolutely.  But I want to have the height be dynamic, so that it shows the image.  Right now, the div ignores the image and will collapse to the content of the text. How can I get the div to show the whole image?

```
<div style="position:relative; height:auto">
    <img style="position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Why are you using an absolute-positioned image in the div? Eliminate that and the div will adjust its height to fit its contents automatically. If you are looking to pad the image or what not, there are better ways to go about that. Otherwise you can use JavaScript to get the image dimensions and adjust the div's size dynamically.

Comment: I using this technique in an html editor so the user can drag the image and move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements that are absolutely positioned are **removed from the normal flow**. That means that all elements will ignore it, as if it didn't exist. To solve your problem, you need to use JavaScript to get the height of the image and adjust the div's height accordingly.